# Regex to match 2 digit but different numbers

Tags: regex

I'm working regex in recent days and now need to make regex which is match with 2 digit but the digits should be different each other
For example followings will be matched:
56, 78, 20 ...
But followings should not be matched:
22, 33, 66 or 99

Already wasted few days for this solution. So any suggestion will be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capture the first digit, then use negative lookahead with a backreference to that first digit to ensure it isn't repeated:

```
(\d)(?!\1)\d
```

https://regex101.com/r/AxH6s8/1

If you need a named group instead:

```
(?<first>\d)(?!\k<first>)\d
```

For a general solution of `n` digits in a row without any repeated digits, you can do something similar, except put `\d*` inside the negative lookahead, before the backreference:

```
^(?:(\d)(?!\d*\g{-1}))+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/AxH6s8/2

Comment: good work. but would you make an example with named group? because my regex is so complex and I can't index them as "\1" or "\2" simply.

Comment: Not sure what language you're using, but you can use `(?<first>\d)(?!\k<first>)\d`

Comment: I'm using php, and I can't share full regex here. How about to name the first digit as "FirstDigit" such as following
`(?'FirstDigit'[0-9])(?!(FirstDigit))[0-9]`
Of course this isn't work so I need to fix that correctly

Comment: @CertainPerformance if the length of digit isn't fixable, is that still possible with only regex? For example, the number can be any of 4 - 8 digit, and there shouldn't be any same value. so 1245, 24567, 46735 are all match, but 11456, 145467 or 356787 are not match.